# Error de conversión de entero a char en C

Tags: array, c

Tengo que revisar que un arreglo compuesto por números de 4 cifras, dichos números deben de estar compuestos por números que estén en el rango de 0 a 7, ejemplo: 1234, 3456, 4567.

Para saber si se cumple el rango primero convierto el entero ingresado a char :

```
   sprintf(conv, "%i", arr[i]);
```

lo hago para separar, unidades, decenas, centenas y millares. Esto es porque tengo que revisar que números hay en unidades, decenas, centenas, etc. y meterlos en un nuevo arreglo.

Ejemplo: 1234
En este caso el número tiene un 4 en las unidades, por lo tanto se va a ir a un arreglo donde solo hay números con 4 en las unidades.

A mi segundo arreglo lo tengo declarado como:

```
char conv[4]
```

en el cual coloco la conversión de entero a char

Al momento de imprimir el valor

```
arr[i]
```

después de ingresarlo permanece igual, pero cuando hago el cambio a char, me cambia el valor, eso solo pasa con el primer número ingresado, con los siguientes no lo cambia.
¿Alguien sabe que puedo hacer o de alguna otra forma de cambiar un entero a char en lenguaje c?

Comment: no necesitas convetirlo a char solo aplicar una condicion con los operadores ```<``` y ```>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer era un problema con el arreglo donde los almacenaba, desconozco la razón exacta por la cual me cambiaba el valor pero solo tuve que aumentar el tamaño del arreglo y empezar a colocarlos desde la posición [1]

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo no entiendo bien del todo tu problema, necesito que muestres mas código o hables mas del asunto, pero te puedo ir adelantando que para validar que un digito este en el rango de 0 a 7 no necesitar hacer una conversión puedes aplicar los operadores "<" o ">" a los tipos char ya que al final por detrás tiene un valor numérico similar.
Mira:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int valid(char*number, size_t length){

    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        if(number[i] < '0' || number[i] > '7'){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char entry[4];
    printf("ingrese un numero o escriba exit para salir\n");

    again:
        printf("escriba - ");
        scanf("%s", entry);

        if(strcmp(entry, "exit") == 1){
            return 0;
        }

        if(valid(entry, 4) == 1){
            printf("respuesta: es valido el digito\n");
        }else{
            printf("respuesta: no es valido el digito\n");
        }

    goto again;
}
```

De este ejemplo la función `valid` es a la que mejor atención debe prestar resuelve tu problema de validar sin conversión, el resto del código es solo para crear una demo que consiste en un bucle donde escribes un numero y este valida sus digito según tu regla.

Comment: Creo que fue algo que no explique bien, por ejemplo yo tengo un numero 1234, a partir del número que hay en las unidades (en este caso 4), lo voy a colocar en otro arreglo que solo va a tener números que tengan un 4 en las unidades, lo mismo con las decenas, centenas y miles.

Comment: Entonces lo que necesitas es tener varios registros (arreglos) y en ellos ir colocando **n** números según sea el caso, por ejemplo un tendrías arreglos para los números que tengas 4 en las unidades, 4 en las decenas y así sucesivamente, a ver dime solo una cosa necesitarias un funciona con una firma así para resolver tu problema: `int dameUnidades(int miNum);` y otra `int dameDecenas(int miNum)` y así irías obteniendo las unidades, decenas, centenas y miles.

Comment: Exacto.

Ya lo resolví, era un problema con la primera posición (desconozco la razón en especifico), lo único que hice fue aumentar en uno el arreglo a donde los mandaba.

Comment: @Hotel_Bar Nunca sabremos la razón exacta porque no incluiste el código (con el problema) en la pregunta.